# SQL script for postgis column name with colon

Tags: postgis, sql

I have an sql script that creates some tables from the default planet_osm_point, planet_osm_line, planet_osm_polygon tables which are created with the osm2pgsql command line tool.

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "aero-poly";

 CREATE TABLE "aero-poly" AS ( 

  SELECT way,aeroway 

  FROM planet_osm_polygon

 WHERE "aeroway" IN ('apron','runway','taxiway','helipad')

 ORDER BY z_order ASC );

CREATE INDEX "aero-poly_way_idx" ON "aero-poly" USING gist (way);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "agriculture";

CREATE TABLE "agriculture" AS ( 

 SELECT way,landuse FROM planet_osm_polygon

 WHERE "landuse" IN    ('allotments','farm','farmland','farmyard','orchard','vineyard')

ORDER BY z_order ASC );

 CREATE INDEX "agriculture_way_idx" ON "agriculture" USING gist (way);
```

and more ....

Some columns in the default tables mentioned above, have names that contain a colon (:) like this: seamark:type.

How may I use this name (seamark:type) in the sql script?

Is there a way to escape the colon (:)?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to pass a table name or a column name with a colon in as a parameter to a plpgsql script?

Comment: Valid SQL identifiers start with an alpha, and permit alphanumeric and underscore as subsequent characters.  Some RDBMSes may allow exceptions, but utilizing those exceptions is a violation of best practice --  It's far better to map the colon (and any other non-conformant character) to underscore.

Comment: Aren't these values used for key value pairs, and using postgres HSTORE, can actually be useful... is there a reason you want to get rid of it?

Comment: Try wrapping in backticks, like `\`seamark:type\``

Comment: @elrobis that only works for MySQL; [more on that here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL)

Comment: Easy, use double quotes like `"seamark:type"` [read more here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)